# Update statement using aggregate function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

In an interview they asked me to write query "update the rows that has maximum percentage"...the column consists of `studentName,maths,science,percentage`...

Please help me to write update query using aggregate function...

Answer (score 4):

```
update  YourTable
set     col1 = 42
where   percentage = 
        (
        select  max(percentage)
        from    YourTable
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07170/9)

```
create table dummy (user_id int,name varchar(50),percentage int)
insert into dummy values(1,'Amit',99);
insert into dummy values(2,'Michle',80);
insert into dummy values(3,'Naval',60);
insert into dummy values(4,'Jack',56);

update dummy set percentage='100'
where percentage=(select max(percentage) from dummy)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT 
     studentName, maths, science, 
     r = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY percentage DESC)
  FROM dbo.table_name
)
UPDATE x 
  SET studentName = studentName + ' - Gold star'
  WHERE r = 1;
```